# What is the best way to split css files for IE through assets:precompile assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the  [CssSplitter module](https://gist.github.com/2398394) by [CristianPeters](https://github.com/ChristianPeters). And I am hoping to have the split occur during the assets:precompile task and the only way I have been successful so far is to patch the Sprockets::StaticCompiler. Hoping there is a better way to do it.

I appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1):

When confronted to this problem, I just split my manifest in 2 :

- having 1 for base (reset, twitter bootstrap, …) and
- the other for application specific CSS

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing stylesheets specifically for the IEs, it's best not to concatenate them all together. Therefore, I would have a main manifest file, where I would load all my general stylesheet files together, and 1/2/3 manifest(s) for the IE(s) using the conditional comments (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %> // main manifest
<!--[if IE 6]>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :ie6 %> // ie6 manifest
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> ....
```

in this manner I would be assured that the css loading performance wouldn't be hurt in the non-IE browsers and that my IE-specific stylesheets would not be loaded for the various versions in which they are anyways not supposed to be loaded (IE6 corrections in IE7, p.ex.).